# Direct travel from Dublin to Reykjavik

Tags: iceland, dublin, reykjavik

I'm planning to visit Reykjavik from Dublin some time near Christmas. Apparently there is no direct flight from Dublin. Since I'm not Irish National, I cannot travel through any other place other than Dublin/Ireland.

Few options are available from Belfast/Northern Ireland but as I'm not Irish national I cannot directly take flight form there as it comes under the UK. Another option is to transit through another UK airport, which is pretty costly and I may even need UK visa.

Is there any direct flight available from Dublin to Reykjavik (if not any other place in Iceland)? I have tried in Skyscanner and some other flight booking sites but none seems to be fetching a specific result.

Comment: Belfast is in the UK

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. If you want to find prices for flights from Dublin to Reykjavik, there are many flight search engines that can do that. WW ("WOW air") has a thrice weekly direct service on the city pair, but it is only seasonal. Edit: between 26 Oct and 21 Dec it runs on Mondays & Fridays

Comment: @Calchas I see how this question does not seem so hard to answer as using the right tool is enough. But many (most?) questions can be answered with little search on the web, that does not make them uninteresting/unclear. And the constraint of not flying through specific countries for visa reason is quite common, even though flight search engines do not provide convenient tools for that (direct flight option is usually an advanced setting, and not all search engines offer to avoid a specific country/airport).

Comment: Did you check the puddle jumpers? There's air fields in the Faroes with very, VERY relaxed transit controls.  Voting this question as 'unclear'.  Please edit your question to get very specific, thanks.

Comment: @Vince If we are allowed to offer flight booking recommendations and the question is interpreted thusly then I will withdraw my "close" suggestion.

Comment: https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Dublin/Reykjavik

Comment: Sorry for not being specific in what I'm asking - edited my question as advised above. The below answer pretty much answered my doubts.

Comment: If you are resident in Ireland, I would expect you to have little difficulty getting a visa for either UK or Schengen area.

Comment: @djclayworth: In fact, Iceland is part of Schengen, isn't it? So if OP has permission to enter Iceland, they should be able to connect through any Schengen country. Maybe Paris, Amsterdam, Copenhagen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [tourism board of Iceland](http://www.visiticeland.com/plan-your-trip/travel-to-iceland/fly-to-iceland/), both Iceland Air and WOW Air have seasonal (so not during the whole year) direct flights between Dublin and Reykjavik.

A [Skyscanner search](http://www.skyscanner.ca/transport/flights/dub/is/cheapest-flights-from-dublin-to-iceland.html?adults=1&children=0&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=1&preferdirects=true&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&oym=1512&iym=1512) shows that unfortunately there is no direct flight during the month of December 2015 (or that flights have not been published yet, so that might be worth checking ~3 months before your dates of travel). On WOW Air website, we can see that the airline actually operates direct flights on Fridays and Mondays, in December.

Regarding your initial question about prices, it is unfortunately not predictable and can vary a lot, so you will have to use a booking engine to figure how much it will cost you, depending on your travel dates and when you fly.

Comment: The timetable is published for October to December: WW852 KEF0620 – 0840DUB 320 15 and WW853 DUB1110 – 1335KEF 320 15

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vince. I was fiddling in Skyscanner and other Flight booking websites and was not getting a specific result. WOW Air is the right place for me. Thanks again for pointing me in right direction.

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to enter Iceland, which is part of the Schengen Area, you are also able to enter all other parts of the Schengen Area - unless you are in some very unusual circumstances. There are direct, year-round flights to Iceland from Paris, Munich, Frankfurt, Copenhagen and Amsterdam amongst others. For example, the cheapest flight to Rejkjavik from Dublin on Sat Aug 22nd goes through Copenhagen.